# How to delete data in datagridview and database in other form?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a serviced-based database Customer. I view its contents in Form1 datagridview.

I made a new Form. Form2 to delete Form1's datagridview contents.

Costumers table has the following columns:

```
CustomerID, CustomerName, Address, ContactNumber
```

This is the code that i am using and its not working whats wrong?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Database1Entities db1Entities = new Database1Entities();
        var customerToDelete = (from i in db1Entities.Customers
                                where i.CustomerID == 1201
                                select i).FirstOrDefault();
        if (customerToDelete != null) 
        {
            db1Entities.Customers.DeleteObject(customerToDelete);
            db1Entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a break point and see if you are getting an object in `costumerToDelete`, you may also try `db1Entities.DeleteObject(costumerToDelete);`

Comment: I don't know what break point is.

Comment: See: [How to set a simple breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k80ex6de(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: how do i get reputation so can i put a printscreen?